# How to set marginLeft and marginRight in HighCharts5

Tags: highcharts

HighCharts 5 introduced the ability to use a theme for styling rather than setting it with javascript.  I'm in the process of migrating all styles into sass, but I haven't found a way to set the marginLeft / marginRight property for a chart.

Pre v5, you would set the margin like this:

```
$('#chart').highcharts({
        chart : {
            marginLeft :29,
            marginRight: 16
        }
...
});
```

I want to remove the styling, and migrate it to a sass file.  I'm not sure which class name I need to hook onto, since nothing I've tried has worked thus far.  I'm new to working with svgs, what am I missing?

```
#chart {
    margin-left: 29px;
    margin-right: 16px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Highcharts styled mode you can style elements with properties which are supported in SVG. SVG does not support padding or margin attributes - instead you need to manually calculate spacing and include that information in element's x, y attributes (or transform, etc.) and this is what Highcharts does.

Comment: I knew it was derived from other properties, but I was still hoping that there was some type of transformation I could apply to get it 'close enough'.  I ended up setting generically in script.